# Codeigniter Categories Menu

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

public function category() {

```
//Get Article View
$data['articles'] = $this->Article_model->get_categories_t('id','DESC');
//Get Articles

//Load View

$this->load->view('cate', $data);
```

}
and my model

```
public function get_categories($order_by = null, $sort = 'DESC', $limit = null, $offset = 0) {
$this->db->select('a.*, c.name as category_name');
$this->db->from('articles as a');
$this->db->join('categories AS c', 'a.category_id = c.id ','LEFT');
if($limit != null) {
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
}
if($order_by != null) {
    $this->db->order_by($order_by, $sort);
}
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();}
```

my problem is view data is all articles not for selected category

i don't understand what i do wrong so any help please

Comment: We can't see neither your model nor controller

Comment: could you clarify the question? are you trying to retrieve articles? or categories? or Articles in Categories? Or Both? or Million Dollar Space Cowboy Astronauts? and as @adrienXL stated, please post the code for your controller and model.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. For us to help you, you need to be clear about what's going wrong and what we can do to help you. What error id you see? what are you expecting instead (if it was working). What have you done to try to fix the problem? what happened when you googled any error message you got? etc etc - more information helps us to help you quicker.